# Why is there no flash video player that holds on to *all* cached data blocks (even if the user skips forwards and back)?

Tags: flash

Is this fundamentally not possible on the flash platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like to say "impossible" when it comes to programming as there are always solutions, it's just whether or not the solutions are worthwhile.

The cached blocks are generated server-side, and are sent to Flash as independently generated FLV files. Each time the user seeks to a spot that is outside the loaded parts of the video, the server needs to generate a new FLV file from that location.

It may be possible to intelligently stream sections until the next block of cached video, stop the stream, then as it plays switch between the cached videos depending on where the user seeks to. However I'd imagine this to be a very ugly and hacky solution, and not to mention the jumpy playback as it switches videos